# How to interpolate across a convex polygon?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have a convex polygon with $N$ verticies $v_i = (x_i, y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and each vertex is assigned a scalar value $k_i \in \mathbb{R}$

I want a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that takes a point $p$ on the polygon and returns a value such that for all i $f(v_i) = k_i$ and the function is continuous and differentiable and that minimizes its higher derivatives.

For a line segment with two vertexes you can just:

$$
     f(p) = k_0 + {{(k_1 - k_0)|p-v_0| }\over{|v_1 - v_0|}}
$$

ie a linear interpolation.

But how do you do it for $N > 2$ ?

(The particular case I'm interested in is a regular hexagon, so if there is an answer specific to that but the general case is too hard that's fine too.)

Comment: Could you use the property that the convex hull of a set of $N$ points is $\{\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i v_i\mid\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_i=1\}$. Now weight the expression in this set definition by your coefficients $k_i$ as you do for the interval to yield the function you want?

Comment: @DavidSheard: How do I work out the values of $\lambda_i$ that correspond to a given point $p$ ?

Comment: @DavidSheard That doesn't work, unfortunately, as the representation of a point as $\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i v_i$ is not unique, nor is the resulting function differentiable. BTW, it is not at all clear in which sense "higher derivatives" (all of them?!) should be minimal. I'd consider identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane, and using the good old Lagrange interpolation polynomial. It would be rather simple in the special case of a regular hexagon.

Comment: I think this works for triangles (which in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are simplexes) and is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system.  This is the method we use in computer graphics to interpolate vertex attributes when rendering triangle meshes.  It works because $\lambda_i$ is unique in that case.  I think what I'm going to try is dividing up the regular hexagon into six triangles - assigning the newly synthesized center vertex the average of $k_i$, and then using barycentric interpolation on the triangle that contains $p$.

Comment: @wasn'tme: I didn't really understand the complex / Lagrange suggestion. You mean this stuff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial ?  If you could show working in an answer it would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Fixing *any* triangulation of your polygon and using barycentric coordinates within those triangles would give you a continuous interpolation function, naturally. But it wouldn't be differentiable along the borders of those triangles, most likely.

Concerning Lagrange interpolation polynomials: let's explain it for the case of a regular hexagon, indeed. More precisely, let's assume that your nodes are (written as complex numbers)
$$v_l=e^{il\pi/3}$$ for $l=0,\ldots,5$. Then, we have $$\omega(z)=(z-v_0)\ldots(z-v_5)=z^6-1,$$ and the basic polynomials will be
$$\ell_l(z)=\frac{\omega(z)}{\omega'(v_l)(z-v_l)}=\frac{z^6-1}{6v^5_l(z-v_l)}.$$ It's clear that $\ell_l(v_j)$ is $1$ for $l=j$, and $0$, otherwise, exactly as in the real case. So
$$f(z)=\sum^5_{l=0}k_l\,\ell_l(z)$$ will be an interpolation function. Now
$$\frac{z^6-1}{z-v_i}=\frac{z^6-v^6_i}{z-v_i}=\sum^5_{j=0}v^{5-j}_i\,z^j,$$ i.e.
$$\ell_l(z)=\frac16\,\sum^5_{j=0}v^{-j}_l\,z^j.$$ So the interpolation function will be
$$f(z)=\sum^5_{j=0}c_j\,z^j,$$ where
$$c_j=\frac16\,\sum^5_{l=0}k_l\,v^{-j}_l.$$ Since your $k_i$ are real, you need only the real part of $f(z)$. BTW, both real and imaginary part of $z^j=(x+iy)^j$ are harmonic polynomials in $x$ and $y$, so this function should have relatively nice derivatives.